# Local host error in vsc your site can't be reached

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIIN7.png)

hi, I just tried to create a resume builder
that source code taken from the  GitHub profile
I took the fork that code and files to my repo,

i  changed localhost 8080 to 5000 and also 4000,3000 tried but it was showing local host error

why it was showing

This is the fork link or any https://github.com/NandhipatiGanesh/Resume-Builder

i want to run successfully and implement like able to download the resume copy

Answer (score 0):

It give refuse connection.

Common causes that result in localhost refusing to connect:

- The server being blocked by the firewall.
- Localhost doesn't resolve to 127.0.0.1.
- Apache failing to run properly.
- DNS failing to function.
- The server being accessed from the wrong port.
- The browser settings blocking the connection.

For troubleshooting do bellow steps:

1. Temporary disable the firewall
2. Check localhost IP address:
   Localhost and the IP address 127.0.0.1 are not completely synonymous. In most
   cases,
   127.0.0.1 is used for loopback, however not exclusively. For instance, IPv6
   systems link the localhost to the address : :1.
3. Check Browser Settings.
   Make sure the browser is not responsible for causing the localhost error.
   Start by navigating to localhost in a different browser. If the connection
   establishes, then the settings in the initial browser are the issue.Often, browsers automatically redirect HTTP addresses to HTTPS causing the localhost refused to connect error.

Hop this should help you :)

Comment: {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "https://localhost:1050",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Please pardon for asking this, but were you able to successfully run the project?

If yes, please ensure that your system understands 'localhost' and resolves it to '127.0.0.1'.

If you're unable to add a DNS resolution then change the value for `proxy` in `package.json` to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` if 5000 is desired port.

Answer (score 0):

Click in wamp logo --> apache-->httpd.config file  --> search for listen and change port to #Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).